# R programming, Random forest through caret

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I'm newbie in R and I want to implement the random forest algorithm using the caret package.

Is there any useful tutorial, step by step?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most packages contain a manual, and many also include vignettes.

A quick look at the CRAN page for `caret` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html shows that this packages is particularly well documented.

It contains 4 vignettes:

- caret Manual – Data and Functions
- caret Manual – Variable Selection
- caret Manual – Model Building
- caret Manual – Variable Importance

Start there.

Answer (score 1):

A few more things appeared about caret package since the question was originally asked. Two tutorials by Max Kuhn, maintainer of caret, I found particularly useful.
[YouTube caret webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Jbb2ItbTC4) and [useR! 2013 tutorial](http://www.edii.uclm.es/~useR-2013/Tutorials/kuhn/user_caret_2up.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Another two excellent starting points are:

1. Max Kuhn and Kjell Johnson - Applied Predictive Modeling (2013) - http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/
2. `caret` webpage - http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html